# Compile multiple embedded Elm app

Tags: elm

I'm trying to understand the "elm-make" command. I built 2 .elm files call `Foo.elm` and `Bar.elm`. I'd like to display them in a HTML file of this format :

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="elm.js"></script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <h2>Foo</h2>
    <div id="foo-app"></div>
    <h2>Bar</h2>
    <div id="bar-app"></div>
  </body>

  <script type="text/javascript">
    Elm.embed(Elm.Foo, document.getElementById("foo-app"));
    Elm.embed(Elm.Bar, document.getElementById("bar-app"));
  </script>
</html>
```

But `Elm.Foo` and `Elm.Bar` do not exist. Only `Elm.Main`.

Tried to compile with this command: `elm make Foo.elm Bar.elm --output elm.js`. What am I doing wrong ?

Comment: there may be a way to do what you want, but it is unlikely to be idiomatic. You should move from two components on your page to one component that has 2 sub-components - Foo and Bar

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It's because I did not have the module declared at the top of my files, so it implied `Main` :

```
module Foo where
```